# How to get or set `env` different value from a user in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, laravel-environment

I am trying to set some of `ENV` values from the user end dynamically. I want to use multiple sms gateway services so that user can use any one from multiple gateways. Multiple services have different `api`, `sid` or `token`. I am saving these  service providers credentials in `sms_gateways` table and trying to use these credentials from this table instead of hand code in controller method. But, I am getting in trouble to use like this. I am trying something like this -

```
public function storeSMS(Request $request)
{
    $smsGateway = $request->smsgatewayname;
    if ($smsGateway['value'] == 'Twilio') {
            $twilio = SmsGateway::where('name', 'Twilio')->first();

            //return $twilio->sid;
            //*here I want to use $twilio->sid value inside env. Is it possible?
            $sid    = env( 'TWILIO_SID' );
            $token  = env( 'TWILIO_TOKEN' );
            $client = new Client($sid, $token);
            $request->validate([
                'text'=>'required',
                'contact'=>'required'
            ]);

            $now = Carbon::now();
            $datetime = explode(' ', $now);


            $numbers_in_arrays = explode( ',' , $request->contact );
            $message = $request->text;
            $count = 0;
            foreach( $numbers_in_arrays as $number )
            {
                $count++;
                $client->messages->create(
                               '+'.$number,
                               [
                                   'from' => env( 'TWILIO_FROM' ),
                                   'body' => $message,
                               ]
                );

                $outbox = new SmsOutbox();
                $outbox->contact = '+'.$number;
                $outbox->text = $message;
                $outbox->send_date = $datetime[0];
                $outbox->send_time = $datetime[1];
                $outbox->is_send = 1;
                $outbox->save();
            }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: if you are using multiple if conditions, then what's the benefit of saving data in database

Comment: ENV file is the server settings and should not be used like this.

Comment: It's better to use records saved in database rather than changing env variables

Comment: Already I am saving Twilio credentials into table `sms_gateways` from user end and I am not understanding how can I make this dynamic and also I want to pass variable value from database in `services.php` inside `env` or instead of `env`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a simpler approach. What about adding two fields named sid and token to the sms_gateways table.

```
Schema::table('sms_gateways', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('sid');
    $table->string('token');
})
```

So from the controller, you can say something like:

```
$gateway = SmsGateway::where('name', $request->smsgatewayname)->first();

$client = new Client($gateway->sid, $gateway->token);
// Or you can also make it even simpler.
// $client = new Client($gateway);
```